# SNAP C++ string type issue std::string to TStr

Tags: c++

In the **SNAP Library** there's a method that allows me to save a file in my pc here it is:

```
TSnap::SaveEdgeList(G, q, "Edge list format");`
```

In this function the 2nd argument its type is **TStr** which represents string types in **SNAP library**

I have a `string^` variable that contains a full directory of where I want to put my file like this (P.S: it contains only one backslash so i have to replace it with double backslash)

```
string^ filename = openFileDialog1->FileName;
```

Then i convert filename variable of type `string^` to `std::string` like this:

```
std::string s = filename->ToString;
```

What I want to do is to give the content of the string variable `s` to a **TStr** variable and with the help of of fellow members here i did like this:

```
TStr q = s.c_str();;
```

But unfortunately it still gives an error:

```
error C3867: 'System::String::ToString': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Does anyone have a suggestion, or an alternative solution, or something?

Comment: The error is most likely related to `std::string s = filename->ToString;` which should be `std::string s = filename->ToString();`

Comment: nope when i do that it gives an error caus ToString without () is a Function of the type string^ not string (there's a difference)

Comment: No, the error is [EXACTLY](https://imgur.com/a/3Deauj8) because of that

Comment: @KillzoneKid well here 's the error that gives me: `1>c:\users\morganis\source\repos\project4\project4\myform.h(201): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'System::String ^' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
1>c:\users\morganis\source\repos\project4\project4\myform.h(201): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using System Strings [component extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/string-cpp-component-extensions). In this case you can use marshalling for conversion from `System::String ^` to `std::string`. Include: `<msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>` and use `msclr::interop::marshal_as` method, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

class Dialog
{
public:
    System::String^ FileName()
    {
        return "name";
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Dialog *openFileDialog1 = new Dialog;
    System::String^ filename = openFileDialog1->FileName();
    std::string s = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(filename->ToString());

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much although the only thing i did is: `std::string s = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(filename);`

Comment: Yes, it looks like direct String ^ to std::string marshalling is also supported. Glad you sorted it.